# Set POD own IP to hostaliases

Tags: kubernetes

As you know, in k8s, we can set additional entry in /etc/hosts with hostAliases in deployment.yaml like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
```

But I want the ip is the POD own IP, then I assign a hostname to the POD. e.g.

```
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "$POD_IP"
    hostnames:
    - "myname"
```

Is is possible? and how to?

Comment: can't you just use localhost?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible that way. Kubectl has a condition that hostAliases[].ip must be a valid IP. There is no way to insert there anything but an IP.

That said, there are other solutions:

- By default kubernetes add to /etc/hosts an entry for POD_IP and POD_NAME, so maybe you can use that.
- You can always modify the entrypoint of the container to write that entry in /etc/hosts. Here is an example using the downward API:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox:1.24
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - echo $MY_POD_IP myname >> /etc/hosts;
          <INSERT YOU ENTRYPOINT HERE>
      env:
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
  restartPolicy: Never`

Comment: Thanks. But k8s doc said direct update /etc/hosts is not suggested: Modification not using HostAliases is not suggested because the file is managed by Kubelet and can be overwritten on during Pod creation/restart.    at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/.   Is there any side effect with this approach?

Comment: You're right, it'd be better use another solution than modifying /etc/hosts. Anyway, as the docs say, this file is overwritten in every pod creation or restart, but the entrypoint is also executed in every creation/restart. I think this paragraph suggest not to modify /etc/hosts during runtime.

Comment: @Ignacio: It doesn;t work to me.. It says permission denied.